# RoutedEventConverter не может обработать событие Checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть такой шаблон для checkBox

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomCheckBox" TargetType="CheckBox">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="11, 0, 0, 0">                
                <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="30" Height="19" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Ellipse x:Name="CheckBoxBackCircle" Width="50" Height="50" Fill="#F8F8FA" Opacity="0">
                        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="-15" Y="-15"/>
                        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Path x:Name="CheckBoxSquare" Data="M.5,12.5 l0,4 q0,2 2,2 l15,0 q1,0 1,-2 l0,-14 q0,-2 -2,-2 l-15,0 q-1,0 -1,2 l0,10" Stroke="#D6D9DF" StrokeThickness="1.4" StrokeDashArray="69.5" Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                    <Path x:Name="CheckBoxCheck" Data="M.5,12.5 l7,6 l11,-15" Stroke="#D6D9DF" StrokeThickness="1.4" StrokeDashArray="28" StrokeDashOffset="28" />
                </Canvas>
                <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentControl>
            </StackPanel>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>

                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="CheckBoxBackCircle" TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="1" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"></DoubleAnimation>                                
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="CheckBoxSquare" TargetProperty="Stroke.Color">
                            <ColorAnimation To="#6FA2F6" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"></ColorAnimation>                                
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>

                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="CheckBoxBackCircle" TargetProperty="Opacity">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="0" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"></DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="CheckBoxSquare" TargetProperty="Stroke.Color">
                            <ColorAnimation To="#D6D9DF" Duration="0:0:0:0.2" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"></ColorAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>

                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="CheckBoxSquare" TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="-69.5" Duration="0:0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Проблема заключается в этом триггере

```
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="CheckBoxSquare" TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset">
                            <DoubleAnimation To="-69.5" Duration="0:0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
```

Вот CheckBox с эти шаблоном

```
<CheckBox Template="{StaticResource CustomCheckBox}" FontSize="17" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></CheckBox>
```

**Ошибка**:

[image: NotSupportedException: RoutedEventConverter не может выполнить преобразование из System.String.]

Если задать другое значение для атрибута `RoutedEvent`, например MouseMove, то всё заработает (но кажется это работает далеко не со всеми Event'ами, т.к. для `Click` и `Unchecked` выскакивает та же ошибка).

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Click">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard TargetName="CheckBoxSquare" TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset">
                <DoubleAnimation To="-69.5" Duration="0:0:0:1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

Нужно прописать CheckBox.Click и должно заработать. Проверил.
Так же можно и CheckBox.Checked

Comment: Спасибо за скорый и верный ответ!

Comment: @zodiak1 если интересно, то вот по ссылке https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventtrigger.routedevent?view=netframework-4.8 в комментарии написано "Если для шаблона или стиля, содержащего этот EventTrigger параметр, не TargetType указано свойство, необходимо задать для имени события имя класса, используя ClassName.EventName синтаксис."

Comment: спасибо за уделённое мне время)!